# Pushwoosh Web SDK not working in ES5

Tags: angularjs, web, ecmascript-6, babeljs, pushwoosh

I am using Pushwoosh Web SDK 2.0^ to register my device (Browser) Id. and to get it token, However the Object doesnt get constructed, because Pushwoosh is using ES6 and promises while I am using ES5 in my project. is there a way to get PushWoosh Object so I can use the other APIs in their SDK?

I was following [Web Push SDK 2.0](http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/web-sdk-20), but [this](http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/web-sdk-20) didn't worked out for me.

PS: I am using Angular 1.5 on front end.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All browsers that support web pushes also support promises.
You can use compiled source:

- git clone git@github.com:Pushwoosh/web-push-notifications.git
- cd web-push-notifications && npm install
- npm run build:lib
- take source from lib/ directory and copy to your project